# Custom Button inheritance (like in OOP rules)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have made custom Button in QML and I want it to be the base item for all buttons in my project. What I want is to derive (like in OOP) buttons from it to change functionality. At first, every derived button should have its own `onClicked` response.

Is this possible in QML and if it is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.

Here is an example of my `BaseButton` type. When `BaseButton` is clicked it emits a custom signal, in my code it's `sgnClicked`.

### BaseButton.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id:idButton
    signal sgnClicked()
    signal sgnClickMaintained()
    signal sgnEntered()
    signal sgnExited()
    signal sgnReleased()
    signal sgnPressed()
    signal sgnCanceled()
    property alias label: idText
    property alias text: idText.text
    property string iconSourceUp:""
    property string iconSourceDown:""
    property string iconSourceDisabled:""
    property alias backgroundWidth: background.width
    property alias backgroundHeight: background.height
    property alias backgroundRect: backgroundRect
    property alias hover: touchArea.enabled

    width: 100
    height: 20
    Text{
        id:idText
        //text: "Button"
        color:"white"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pointSize: 12
    }
    //if maintained at each 300 ms resend signal
    Timer{
        id:timer
        running: false
        repeat: true
        interval: 300
        onTriggered: sgnClickMaintained()
    }
    Image{
        id:background
        z: -1
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        source:iconSourceUp
        visible: source.toString() !== ""
    }
    Gradient {
        id:idGradient
        GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: touchArea.pressed ? "#ccc" : "#eee" }
        GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: touchArea.pressed ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: backgroundRect
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        border.color: "#888"
        color: enabled ?"":"lightgrey"
        radius: 4
        z: -1
        visible: !background.visible
        gradient: enabled ?idGradient:null
    }

    MouseArea{
        id: touchArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onCanceled: idButton.sgnCanceled()
        onClicked:
        {
            idButton.sgnClicked()
        }
        onEntered: idButton.sgnEntered()
        onExited: idButton.sgnExited()
        onPressAndHold: {
            timer.restart()
            idButton.sgnClickMaintained()
        }
        onReleased:{
            idButton.state = "up"
            timer.stop()
            idButton.sgnReleased()
        }
        onPressed:
        {
            idButton.state = "down"
            idButton.sgnPressed()
        }
    }
    onEnabledChanged: {
        if(enabled === false)
        {
            idButton.state = "disabled"
            timer.stop()
        }
        else{
            idButton.state = "up"
        }
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "down"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: background
                source: iconSourceDown
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "disabled"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: background
                source: iconSourceDisabled
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "up"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: background
                source: iconSourceUp
            }
        }
    ]

    Component.onCompleted:{
        if(enabled)
        {
            state = "up"
        }
        else
        {
            state = "disabled"
        }
    }
}
```

To make a new Button inheriting from `BaseButton` you should instantiante the `BaseButton` as root item and in the slot `onSgnClicked` write what you want your button should do when clicked.

### CustomButton.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

BaseButton {
    width: 100
    height: 50
    onSgnClicked: {
        //do something
    }
}
```